# How to bit-shift an immediate value

Tags: assembly, arm

Is there a way to bit-shift an immediate value like this :

`MOV    R0, #N, LSR #1` (not working)

or do I have to do this in two instructions ?

`MOV     R0, #N
MOV     R0, R0, LSR #1`

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I want the value of N/2 in R0

Comment: Well then just use an immediate which is the value of N/2 !

Comment: I could, but I dont understand why it is possible to shift a register but not an immediate value

Comment: Why would they waste instruction encodings on that? Your assembler might support evaluation of constant expressions though (i.e. `MOV R0, #(N >> 1)` or `MOV R0, #(N / 2)` or something like that)

Comment: What Michael said. Although the cheekier response is that _all_ immediate values (in regular ARM data processing instruction encodings, at least) are already inherently shifted, because the underlying encoding is actually an 8-bit value rotated right by twice a 4-bit number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the assembler worry about encoding immediates into machine code using the barrel shifter.

As Michael says, assemblers support expressions on assemble-time constants, so you should be able to write

```
MOV R0, #(N >> 1)
```

as long as that results in a value that can be encoded using the limited number of immediate bits and rotate count.

If you aren't sure it will always assemble, and are ok with leaving the choice up to the assembler, use the pseudo-instruction that gets a constant into a register in whatever way is most efficient:

```
ldr r0, =(N >> 1)     @ I think I have the right syntax here
```

This assembles to either a mov-immediate, or a PC-relative load from a nearby constant, or maybe another choice.

---

If you care about which encoding is used for `mov r0, #value` (e.g. `0x4 ROR 2` vs. `0x1 ROR 0`), then use:

```
mov r0, #0x4, #2        @ rotates to the right by 2.
```

---

Unlike `mov` with register operands, `mov`-immediate doesn't offer a choice of barrel-shifter options, like LSL, LSR, ROL, ROR.  It's always rotate-right, and the count has to be even for ARM encoding.

IIRC, Thumb allows any count, but there are fewer immediate bits.

See the [ARMv7 reference manual](http://liris.cnrs.fr/~mmrissa/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=armv7-a-r-manual.pdf) for more info.

Comment: The syntax for an explicit immediate encoding is `#imm8, #rot`, e.g. `mov r0, #4, #2` for a non-standard `mov r0, #1` (the rotation is to the right, not the left).